# "Ruby-esque" if else conditional statements

Tags: ruby

I'm currently reading [The Ruby Programming Language](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516178.do), and I am not sure how to read Ruby-esque if else statements properly. Can you help me write the ruby code below in the second code block in regular if-else statements like this?

```
if some_condition
  return x
else
  return y
end
```

So the ruby codes I am unsure of are these.

```
minimum = if x < y then x else y end

max = x > y ? x : y
```

Thank you!

Comment: "Can you help me write the following in regular if-else statements like this?" - I don't understand this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of the forms you seem to be having difficulty with make use of an idea Ruby takes from the Functional Programming paradigm: namely, *Everything is an expression, and therefore returns a value*. This is even true for conditional statements, an idea that languages like Java don't really support (for example:

```
public boolean test() {
  boolean x = if (1 > 2 ) { false; } else { true; };
  return x;
}
```

simply isn't syntactically valid).

You can see this in a Ruby terminal:

```
will_be_assigned_nil = false if (1 > 2) # => nil
will_be_assigned_nil # => nil
```

So, to your question.
The first one can be rewritten like this:

```
if x < y
  mininum = x
else
  minimum = y
end
```

The second is like the ternary operator in other languages, and is equivalent to:

```
if x > y
  max = x
else
  max = y
end
```

It's helpful to remember the roots & heritage of languages when trying to understand their constructs. Ruby shares the "More Than One Way To Do It" philosophy with Perl, and idiomatic Ruby code often has a high emphasis on elegance.

The "post-expression"-style conditionals are a good example of this. If I have guard expressions at the start of my methods, it's not uncommon for me to write:

```
raise "Pre-condition x not met" unless x # (or "if !x" , preference thing)
raise "Pre-condition y not met" unless y # etc., etc.
```

instead of

```
if !x
  raise "Pre-condition x not met"
end
if !y
  raise "Pre-condition y not met"
end
```

Comment: I gave you a bit more background, hope it's useful :)